# How do I merge Bitmap side-by-side

Tags: java, android, bitmap, merge, android-canvas

I want to merge two bitmaps side-by-side into one bitmap. The following code is merge sub-bottom. How do I merge side-by-side into one bitmap ?

```
public Bitmap mergeBitmap(Bitmap fr, Bitmap sc) 
{ 

    Bitmap comboBitmap; 

    int width, height; 

    width = fr.getWidth() + sc.getWidth(); 
    height = fr.getHeight(); 

    comboBitmap = Bitmap.createBitmap(width, height, Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888); 

    Canvas comboImage = new Canvas(comboBitmap); 


    comboImage.drawBitmap(fr, 0f, 0f, null); 
    comboImage.drawBitmap(sc, 0f , fr.getHeight(), null); 
    return comboBitmap;

}
```

Comment: Use x -coordinate instead; ``comboImage.drawBitmap(sc, fr.getWidth(), 0f, null)``.

Comment: unfortunately, I am seeing "fr" in screen. sc overflow from screeen

Comment: I think, problem is canvas features. 
code 's first state is 
width = fr.getWidth();
height = fr.getHeight() + sc.getWidth();
After I changed it;
width = fr.getWidth() + sc.getWidth(); 
height = fr.getHeight();

Comment: check this out for similar issue https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38162291/what-is-the-correct-way-to-horizontally-add-some-spaced-image-into-a-canvas/66159316#66159316

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
public Bitmap mergeBitmap(Bitmap fr, Bitmap sc) 
    { 

        Bitmap comboBitmap; 

        int width, height; 

        width = fr.getWidth() + sc.getWidth(); 
        height = fr.getHeight(); 

        comboBitmap = Bitmap.createBitmap(width, height, Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888); 

        Canvas comboImage = new Canvas(comboBitmap); 


        comboImage.drawBitmap(fr, 0f, 0f, null); 
        comboImage.drawBitmap(sc, fr.getWidth(), 0f , null); 
        return comboBitmap;

    }
```

Answer (score 0):

This [article](http://www.jondev.net/articles/Combining_2_Images_in_Android_using_Canvas) goes through the process of combining 2 images one below the other(only works with PNG or JPG ). It will involve passing 2 Bitmaps, which will then get combined using the Canvas class. You can do somme minor changes to get your two images side by side:

```
public Bitmap combineImages(Bitmap c, Bitmap s) { // can add a 3rd parameter 'String loc' if you want to save the new image - left some code to do that at the bottom 
    Bitmap cs = null; 

    int width, height = 0; 

    if(c.getHeight() > s.getHeight()) { 
      width = c.getWidth() + s.getWidth(; 
      height = c.getHeight()); 
    } else { 
      width = c.getWidth() + s.getWidth(); 
      height = s.getHeight(); 
    } 

    cs = Bitmap.createBitmap(width, height, Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888); 

    Canvas comboImage = new Canvas(cs); 

    comboImage.drawBitmap(c, 0f, 0f, null); 
    comboImage.drawBitmap(s, c.getWidth(), 0f, null); 

    // this is an extra bit I added, just incase you want to save the new image somewhere and then return the location 
    /*String tmpImg = String.valueOf(System.currentTimeMillis()) + ".png"; 

    OutputStream os = null; 
    try { 
      os = new FileOutputStream(loc + tmpImg); 
      cs.compress(CompressFormat.PNG, 100, os); 
    } catch(IOException e) { 
      Log.e("combineImages", "problem combining images", e); 
    }*/ 

    return cs; 
  }
```