# What is the correct way to horizontally add some spaced image into a Canvas?

Tags: java, android, android-canvas, android-image, android-bitmap

I am absolutly new in Android development and I have the followind doubt.

I have to draw images one next to each other into a **Canvas** object.

So let to an example: I have this icon (it is pretty huge and I have to resize it):

[image]

So I have to put 3 of these icon one next to each other (adding some white space between an image and the next one).

So I have done something like this:

```
// Load the 2 images for the creation of the "difficulty graphic":
Bitmap chefHatOk = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(), R.drawable.chef_hat_ok);

// Where the previus image will be drawn:
Canvas canvas = new Canvas();
```

So I think that I can add the previous image to the **Canvas** doing something like this:

```
canvas.drawBitmap(smallImage, 0f, 0f, null);
```

I think that the first **0f** value represent the horizontal space before the inserted image (the offset), correct me if I am doing wrong assertion.

So, how can I add 3 of these images one next to each other leaving some white space between an image and the next one?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Something like this should work:

```
Bitmap output = Bitmap.createBitmap(width, height, Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888);
Canvas canvas = new Canvas(output);

int space = 10; // the space between images

for(int i = 0; i < 3; i++) {
    canvas.drawBitmap(smallImage, i * (smallImage.getWidth() + space), 0, null);
}

// do whatever you want with output
```

Answer (score 0):

This should do the work, eg for two image with space horizontal

```
public static mergeImages(Bitmap firstImage, Bitmap secondImage)
{
 Bitmap cs;
 int width, height;
 float space = 60f; // space between image horizontal

 if(firstImage.getWidth() > secondImage.getWidth()) {
 width = firstImage.getWidth() + secondImage.getWidth();
 } else {
 width = s.getWidth() + secondImage.getWidth();
 }
 height = firstImage.getHeight();

 cs = Bitmap.createBitmap(width, height, Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888);

 Canvas comboImage = new Canvas(cs);
 comboImage.drawBitmap(firstImage, 0f, 0f, null);
 comboImage.drawBitmap(secondImage, firstImage.getWidth()+space, 0f, null);

 return cs; // result image
}
```